# How to run a bash script inside a snakemake pipeline

Tags: snakemake

I would like to run a bash script inside the snakemake pipeline. But I do not know how to call the input and output of snakemake in a bash script.

snakemake:

```
rule xxx:
    input:
        "input.vcf"
    output:
        "output.tab"
    shell:
        """
        some_bash.sh {input} {output}
        """
```

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

paste <(bcftools snakemake@input[0] |\
    awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN {print "CHR\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tFILTER"} \
      !/^#/ {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}') \
    \
  <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' snakemake@input[0] |\
    awk 'BEGIN {print "nHet"} {print gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, "")}') \
    \
  <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' snakemake@input[0] |\
    awk 'BEGIN {print "nHomAlt"} {print gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "")}') \
    \
  <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' snakemake@input[0] |\
    awk 'BEGIN {print "nHomRef"} {print gsub(/0\|0|0\/0/, "")}') \
    \
  <(bcftools snakemake@input[0] | awk -F"\t" '/^#CHROM/ {split($0, header, "\t"); print "HetSamples"} \
    !/^#CHROM/ {for (i=10; i<=NF; i++) {if (gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, "", $(i))==1) {printf header[i]","}; if (i==NF) {printf "\n"}}}') \
    \
  <(bcftools snakemake@input[0] | awk -F"\t" '/^#CHROM/ {split($0, header, "\t"); print "HomSamplesAlt"} \
    !/^#CHROM/ {for (i=10; i<=NF; i++) {if (gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "", $(i))==1) {printf header[i]","}; if (i==NF) {printf "\n"}}}') \
    \
  | sed 's/,\t/\t/g' | sed 's/,$//g' > snakemake@output[0]
```

Error I get:

```
[E::main] unrecognized command 'snakemake@input[0]'
[E::main] unrecognized command 'snakemake@input[0]'
[E::main] unrecognized command 'snakemake@input[0]'
[E::hts_open_format] [E::hts_open_format] Failed to open file "snakemake@input[0]" : No such file or directoryFailed to open file "snakemake@input[0]" : No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the input arguments using bash syntax, `snakemake@input[0]` is specifically for R scripts using a `script` directive.

In particular, you can replace `snakemake@input[0]` with `$1`, which gets the first argument to a bash script and `snakemake@output[0]` with `$2`, the second argugment.  To be safe, wrap those with double quotes in case there are spaces in the filenames, e.g. `"$1"`.